# Content files are not working when URL rewrite using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have URL redirecting when someone calls a url like example.com/page/3fssdfs it will be like page?id=3fssdfs  for this I used the following htaccess code.

```
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1
```

So with this the page loads fine when someone visits example.com/page/3fssdfs. However the CSS and image files doesn't load. When I checked the console they appear like this,

```
GET http://example.com/page/assets/css/index.css 404 (Not Found)
```

The css files are stored like example.com/assets

So how can I fix the error? Thanks

**UPDATE here's the full .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if the file does NOT exist (! means NOT, and -f means file exists)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#if the directory does NOT exit (-d stands for directory exists)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC]'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Shouldn't `page/assets/css/index.css` be `/assets/css/index.css`? Or are you trying to get something like `?page=/assets/css/index.css`

Comment: @Gasim the css files are on the root folder, and after the URL rewrite edit the urls look like example.com/page/123 and the server thinks the CSS files are inside page/css/ not in the root folder

Comment: @Gasim to put it simple i need the css files to be loaded, the css files are not loading because the page thinks the css files are in a different folder called page but it's not. Page is only a url rewrite path.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood the question. I don't know how you handle your files but you need to make the files "absolute path". like instead of "assets/css/index.css", it should be "/assets/css/index.css". EDIT: or base tag `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rewrite condition:

```
#if the file does NOT exist (! means NOT, and -f means file exists)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#if the directory does NOT exit (-d stands for directory exists)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
```

Right before your rewrite rule.

If the two above become true, your rule will get rewritten; if not, there won't be any rewrite and you will be able to access the content files.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is still the same. here is the full .htaccess file